# Mistake from cordova.js after getting file from camera

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

We got file, it lies in cache, and i see it in Console
But when i tried to save it and send, i got this mistakes from cordova.js

Wrong type for parameter "newName" of Entry.copyTo: Expected String, but got Number.

Uncaught TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "newName" of Entry.copyTo: Expected String, but got Number.

Error in Success callbackId: File1917405046 : TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "newName" of Entry.copyTo: Expected String, but got Number.

ngCordova installed and injected
Cordova is updated
and i can't send my file, please help me 
**that's my code in controller**

---

```
$scope.attachPhoto = function() {
        $ionicActionSheet.show({
            buttons: [
                { text: '<i class="icon ion-android-image"></i>Перейти в галерею' },
                { text: '<i class="icon ion-android-camera"></i> Сделать фото' }
            ],
            cancelText: 'Cancel',
            cancel: function() {

            },
            buttonClicked: function(index) {
                var options = {
                    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit : false,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions
                };

                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
                    onImageSuccess(imageData);
                    console.log(imageData);

                    function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
                        createFileEntry(fileURI);
                        console.log(fileURI);
                    }
                    function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
                        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
                        console.log(fileURI);
                    }
                    function copyFile(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();

                            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                                var imgBlob = new Blob([ this.result ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
                                $scope.attach = true;
                                $scope.file = imgBlob;
                            };
                            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        });
                        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
                            fileEntry.copyTo(
                                fileSystem2,
                                12345,
                                onCopySuccess,
                                fail
                            );
                        }, fail);
                    }
                    function onCopySuccess(entry) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.images.push(entry.nativeURL);
                            $scope.attach = true;
                            $scope.sendPhoto();
                        });
                    }
                    function fail(error) {
                        console.log("fail: " + error.code);
                    }
                }, function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                console.log(options);
                return true;
            }
        })
    };


    $scope.sendPhoto = function() {

        var data = {
            file: $scope.file
        }
        console.log(data);
        var fd = new FormData(data);

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://eatmeet.ru/serv.php");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
        xhr.send(fd);

    }
```

Comment: please give some feedback mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse a `string` as fileName, not a `number`. Please check the [file documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html).

The correct syntax is:
 `fileEntry.copyTo(parent [DirectoryEntry], newName [DOMString], successCallback [Function], errorCallback [Function]);`

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
    fileEntry.copyTo(
        fileSystem2,
        "12345",
        onCopySuccess,
        fail
    );
}, fail);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this code helped me, and file is coming to server, but i've got new mistake

Comment: @markprog glad to help you. You may going to mark this answer as the right one? (the tick near the vote buttons)